# Fitnesse on Linux with Jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, fitnesse

I've been trying to setup Fitnesse on a centos7 machine with Jenkins but ran into a few problems.

I have Jenkins using the Fitnesse plugin and starting an instance of Fitnesse which it does fine but then it cant seem to connect to the started Fitnesse server with an error message "Fitnesse server NOT started in 30000ms on URL: "

At First I thought it was a problem with localhost not being able to connect to it but I am able to connect on the centos machine using firefox and localhost: while Jenkins is also trying (and failing) to connect to it. So I used telnet to ping it and it produces the following:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
HTTP/1.1 408 Request Time-out
Content-Length: 2131
Connection: close
Server: FitNesse-v20150424
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>Error Occurred</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script>
    document.createElement('header');
    document.createElement('nav');
    document.createElement('section');
    document.createElement('article');
    document.createElement('footer');
   </script>
  <![endif]-->

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/files/fitnesse/images/favicon.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/fitnesse/css/fitnesse_wiki.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/fitnesse/css/fitnesse_pages.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/fitnesse/wysiwyg/wysiwyg.css" media="screen"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/fitnesse/bootstrap/css/fitnesse-bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/files/fitnesse/question.mark/question.mark.css" />

  <script src="/files/fitnesse/javascript/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/files/fitnesse/javascript/fitnesse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="/files/fitnesse/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/files/fitnesse/bootstrap/js/respond.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </head>
 <body class="error">

  <nav class="navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar navbar-default">
   <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="/FrontPage"><span>FitNesse</span></a>
    </div>


   </div>
   <ol class="page-actions btn-group">
 <li class="expandall btn btn-xs">Expand All</li>
 <li class="collapseall btn btn-xs">Collapse All</li>
</ol>

<ol class="breadcrumb">
 <li>Error Occurred</li>
</ol>
  </nav>

  <header>
      </header>

  <article>
    <center>The client request has been unproductive for too long. It has timed out and will now longer be processed.</center>
  </article>


 </body>
</html>

Connection closed by foreign host
```

So it looks like it actually IS conncting to Fitnesse, but Fitnesse isn't responding properly or something? Does anyone have any insight on the problem or possible solutions?

Comment: I can't really help you with the FitNesse plugin. But if your goal is to run your tests on Jenkins and have HTML the reports of the tests I recommend creating a single jUnit test annotated with `@RunWith("FitNesseRunner.class")`. This can then be run by any CI server as a normal Java unit test run. HTML pages describing the tests outcome are generated in your workspace and can be published as artifacts or using the HTML publisher plugin. No need for a special FitNesse plugin. And this setup makes it easy for developers to debug fixtures or reproduce test results from the dev environment...

Comment: More details on running using jUnit at http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.RunningFromJunit

Comment: Thanks Fried, I'll definitely look into this!

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting up this pipeline job on a node?

It seems the Fitnesse plugin connects to Fitnesse from the master always. Hence, localhost will not answer, if fitnesse was started on a node.

For now, you will have to run fitnesse jobs only on the master.